# Javascript Replace Certain Characters of href after the last slash /

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, href

I have this a tag

```
<a id="Link" href="mysite.net/K&N abc 123.html">Link</a>
```

I need to use JavaScript to remove non alphanumeric characters then replace  spaces with a dash `-` and lowercase the result.

So everything after `/K&N abc 123.html` and leave the rest of the href untouched.

The final result would look like this

```
<a id="Link" href="mysite.com/kn-abc-123.html">Link</a>
```

I have some code to start but not quite getting it put together right to give the correct result.

```
var str = document.getElementById("Link").getAttribute("href");
str = str.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
document.getElementById('Link').setAttribute("href",str);
```

Comment: Why not `encodeURIComponent()`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bin.
https://jsbin.com/gojoseduji/3/edit?html,output

```
var href = document.getElementById("Link").getAttribute('href');
var str = href
  // replace each block of whitespace with a single '-' character
  .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
  // Filter out non alphanumerics, excluding : / -
  .replace(/[^\:\/\-\w\s.]+/g, "")
  // get rid of any hyphens that follow a slash
  .replace(/\/-/g, '/')
  .toLowerCase();
```

I just used the whitespace identifier, and make sure to make it global :)

EDIT: Added the condition to strip all non alpha-numerics except [/  -  :]. I stripped the whitespace first and had the second regex ignore the hypens. I also made the variable names different, as your original code modified the variable. Just my preference.

EDIT-AGAINN: This original way was nice, but now there's a few different regEx's, maybe someone with smoother regex skills can condense those down and make a better answer?

Comment: You forgot about the non alphanumerics

Comment: works good. How would you edit the regex to remove a white space directly after `/` and directly preceding `.` instead of replacing with a hyphen. this `www.site.com/ K&N 33 cc    .html` to `www.site.com/kn-33-cc.html`

Comment: never mind. I just used trim() to trim the white space before the .replace regex starts :D

Comment: Yeah actually how would you do it? trim() isn't doing it.

Comment: I edited the code to adjust for that, just use a regex to search for occurrences of '/-'. Although there are alot of different steps and regex's in there now, code smells are arising. Maybe someone with more RegExp skills can condense that down?

Comment: Yeah I always like one liners whenever possible :D But your code does the basic job. The flags you are using in the regex, are they compatible with even old browsers?

Comment: Yup, I believe only the 'y' and 'u' flags are troublemakers for older browsers.  What's implemented here should anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` with a `callback`:

```
var href = document.getElementById("Link").getAttribute('href');

href = href.replace(/^((?:.*?\/{2})?[^\/]*\/)(.+)$/, function($0, $1, $2) {
      return $1 + $2.replace(/[^\w\s.]+/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); });

document.getElementById('Link').setAttribute("href", href);
//=> mysite.net/kn-abc-123.html
```

Or with `ftp://` in URL:

```
str = 'ftp://mysite.net/K&N abc 123.html'

str = str.replace(/^((?:.*?\/{2})?[^\/]*\/)(.+)$/, function($0, $1, $2) {
      return $1 + $2.replace(/[^\w\s.]+/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); });

//=> ftp://mysite.net/kn-abc-123.html
```

Comment: You misunderstand. The link is not always going to be `K&N abc 123.html` I just used it as an example. The code needs to remove all spaces and replace with `-` as well as remove non alphanumeric characters.

Comment: **The code needs to remove all spaces and replace with -** In your example all spaces are replaced with hyphen and all non-word chars are removed except DOT in `.html` (which you haven't clarified in question). btw `Remove` is different from `Replace`

Comment: OK sorry. A simple way to say it is, remove the non alphanumeric characters. Replace spaces with hyphens. Don't alter anything before the last forward slash.

Comment: Similar to you `str.replace(/\/.*$/, function($0) {
    return '/' + $0.replace(/[^.\w\s]+/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
});`.

Comment: @Mike: As you can see this answer is already doing it. However DOT is also a non alphanumeric character and if we remove it it will also become `kn-abc-123html` instead of `kn-abc-123.html`

Comment: @Tushar: Thanks, yes that will work for the case when only segment after last `/` is to be cleaned up. I (probably shouldn't have) assumed that everything after `http://domain.com/` needed to be cleaned up.

Comment: @Tushar: Also that suggested replacement won't work for something like: `http://domain.com/K&N abc 123.html'` as input

Comment: @Mike: Are there other example URLs you have for this this solution didn't work for you?

Comment: yes it could be anything `www.site.com/asdf k asdf.html` could be any combination of words with or without non alphanumeric characters.

Comment: ok for that value above code will produce `www.site.com/asdf-k-asdf.html` Hope that's your expected output as well

Comment: Ok it works but it also strips out the forward slash `/` from the url. the output is `www.site.comasdf-k-asdf.html`

Comment: [No forward slash is not removed, check this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mkmyjxko/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var str = document.getElementById("Link").getAttribute("href");

var lastitem = str.split("/").pop(); //taking out last item after slash 

lastitem = lastitem.split( " " ).map( function(value){ return value.replace(/[*\(\)&/]/g, '').toLowerCase() } ).join( "-" );    //removing special characters and replacing space with hyphen

str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/")) + lastitem;

document.getElementById('Link').setAttribute("href",str);
```

Comment: This one worked but it also stripped out the last slash from the url. :D